# Put a [pin] in [rust-pin]

Tags: support, status-declined, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Cleanup on aisle 3! I created the [pin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pin) tag not realizing there is already a [rust-pin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-pin) tag.

Could one be made the synonym of the other? My preference is for [pin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pin) to be the canonical tag since it's shorter and, given that the name wasn't already used, there doesn't seem to be a need to disambiguate it with other uses of the word "pin".

If you'd rather merge them, or delete the tag I made, that's fine, too.

Comment: There is only 12 questions linked, not important, I agree pin could be used since it's isn't used before and you did a tag description. Just do it at hand and let rust-pin self destroy

Comment: I'll do that in a few days if nobody objects.

Comment: There are no longer any questions tagged `[pin]`. The tag will be deleted by the system automatically.

Comment: It looks like it already happened. Well in that case, I'll rename [tag:rust-pin] to [tag:pin] in a few days if nobody objects.

Comment: What do you mean you'll "rename" the tag? I don't think regular users can rename tags. Also, rust-pin is a better tag than pin, which is altogether too generic.

Comment: Note: this is not the first time the [tag:pin] tag was created. It was previously deleted about 9 years ago.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A "pin" tag will be used for PINs (the numeric passcodes), Pinterest, the Pin Payments API, certificate pinning, pinning things to the top, making electronic pin boards, PINs (again, but it stands for personal identification number) and maybe even hardware pins.

The only name that will keep this on topic is "rust-pin". Let's not revive "pin" as a tag name.

Comment: *"PINs (the numeric passcodes),...,PINs (again, but it stands for personal identification number)"* -  The numeric passcodes _are_ personal identification numbers.